# Substring in batch file

Tags: batch-file

```
User_Name=root;Password=1234;Server=192.168.1.49;DriverID=MySQL;Database=dbTest
```

How can i parse this string in batch-file. All samples about substrings are  get X-to-Y.. But my string is dynamic.

I want to get between `=` and `;` and set the variables:

```
username = root
password = 1234
server = 192.168.1.49
driverid = MySQL
database= dbTest
```

`:~start,length` notation is not fit for me.. Any other option ?

Comment: You mean `user_name` as a variable, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "string=User_Name=root;Password=1234;Server=192.168.1.49;DriverID=MySQL;Database=dbTest"

FOR %%a IN ("%string:;=","%") DO SET %%a

SET

GOTO :EOF
```

You don't say where your string is stored, so I put it in `string`.

The string-substitution replaces each `;` with `","` so the command executed by the `for` id set "user_name=root","password... which is a valid but little-used application of the `set` command.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what the variables will be, then this modification of the method used in aschipfl's answer should suffice, *(subject to reasonable characters)*:

```bat
Set "String=User_Name=root;Password=1234;Server=192.168.1.49;DriverID=MySQL;Database=dbTest"
Set "%String:;="&Set "%"&Set "String="
@Pause
```

*I've left echoing on, so that you can see it in use,*

Answer (score 0):

What about [replacing every `;` by `";"`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html), enclosing the resulting string in between `""`, so you get `"User_Name=root";"Password=1234";...`? This can then be split by a standard [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) (no `/F` option!), because `;` is a standard token separator for `cmd` just like <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, `,` and `=`. The latter is protected by the quotation marks. This is what I mean:

```cmd
set "STRING=User_Name=root;Password=1234;Server=192.168.1.49;DriverID=MySQL;Database=dbTest"
set STRING="%STRING:;=";"%"
for %%I in (%STRING%) do set "$%%~I"
set $
```

I just prepended a `$` sign to every variable name just for easier demonstration (`set $` displays all of them); you may remove it, of course. Note that this approach fails in case the string contains wild-card characters like `*` or `?`.